# Как добавить значок с цифрой (Badge) на элемент меню в Toolbar?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-toolbar, android-menu

**Дано:**

`Toolbar` c элементом меню.

**Задача:**

Добавить кружок с числом. Например для отображения кол-ва покупок в корзине или кол-ва сообщений каких-то.

**Вопрос:**

Таки как это сделать?

Comment: Вы всегда можете добавить в тулбар свои вьюхи, и там хоть иконки с бэджами, хоть видео показывать...

Comment: @YuraIvanov, да, конечно) Однако мне хотелось в данном случае более простого решения. Какое как раз можно через `BadgeDrawable` получить

Comment: Практика показывает, что использование экспериментальных фич - это технический долг прям сразу до написания, все равно придется к этой задаче возвращаться... :)

Comment: @YuraIvanov, и с этим я абсолютно согласен, даже упомянул вскользь это в ответе 3-им словом) Однако, в некоторых случаях такое решение может быть оправдано во имя экономии ресурсов или из желания поэксперементировать. Понятно, что можно сделать любую вещь очень по разному. Например вообще Toolbar не использовать готовый, чтобы не мучиться с его стилизацией и свой запилить, где всё будет под полным контролем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту фичу (эксперементально!) [добавили](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/5e35d14c187b65b32788cce28d758657f1b5aebb) в версии `1.3.0-alpha04` библиотеки `com.google.android.material:material:${materialVersion}`

Пользоваться можно так:

1. Подключаем нужную версию либы:
   `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:${materialVersion}"`
2. В случае, если меню из фрагмента отображаем, пишем в методе `onCreateOptionsMenu`

   ```
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.YOUR_MENU_RESOURSE, menu)

        val badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(requireContext())
        badgeDrawable.number = 5
        badgeDrawable.backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.SOME_COLOR_HERE)
        badgeDrawable.badgeTextColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.SOME_COLOR_HERE)
        badgeDrawable.badgeGravity = BadgeDrawable.TOP_END
        BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, REFERENCE_TO_TOOLBAR, R.id.MENU_ITEM_ID_HERE)

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
   ```
3. Т.к. фича экспериментальная, требуется аннотация над методом, где мы это делаем:
   `@SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")`

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]